# Potential security breach- open google script?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, automation, zapier

I'd like to allow a third party app(Zapier) to execute a google script with access to Admin Directory API within my organization. For that, I'd need to allow everyone with a link to execute this script which takes parameters to create a new user within the organization. Also, if somebody was to be able to edit the script, they could do lots of harm.

Does somebody know how to prevent that from happening or making this whole process secure?
What are the *actual* potential threats?

Cheers,

Comment: What 3rd party service do you need to integrate using Zapier? It might be better to integrate directly with that service if possible. Exposing your app script as a public web app is rife with issues. Anyone with the web app's url can spam requests to that endpoint and exhaust your service quotas gumming up your system.

Comment: This is not a programming question. However, you'd actually be allowing anonymous users to execute the script as you in a read-only manner. The 3rd party can't edit the published script as all edits need to be republished as new revisions by you, with a new link. The process is as secure as the number of people you share the link and the error handling you build into the script so only a request with the correct formatting is accepted. The likelihood of someone guessing the URL and passing the correct parameters is very low.

Comment: @JamesD Passing parameters won't provide sufficient protection against spam attacks. As long as the web app url is hit via a **GET** or **POST** request it will count against the ***Trigger Total Runtime*** quota (since **`doGet(e)`** and **`doPost(e)`** are considered triggers) and also against the ***Simultaneous Execution*** quota. The only real protection is limiting access to trusted parties.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dimu Designs and @James D have already stated, this might not be the best Idea.

> It might be better to integrate directly with that service if possible. Exposing your app script as a public web app is rife with issues. Anyone with the web app's url can spam requests to that endpoint and exhaust your service quotas gumming up your system.

---

> This is not a programming question. However, you'd actually be allowing anonymous users to execute the script as you in a read-only manner.

Also taking into account Quotas you would also have a problem as @Dimu Designs has already stated.

> Passing parameters won't provide sufficient protection against spam attacks. As long as the web app url is hit via a GET or POST request it will count against the Trigger Total Runtime quota (since doGet(e) and doPost(e) are considered triggers) and also against the Simultaneous Execution quota. The only real protection is limiting access to trusted parties.

In the end doing this with Apps Script probably is not the way to go. Doing it internally through a intranet would be a much better solution. But if doing it with Apps Script is your only option beware of the risk involved in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
For now I implemented a token that has to be provided to execute the purpose of this script. Still, the doGet(e) can be hit by a request. 
Hence, @Dimu Designs, I tried to whitelist the third-party app, but when the script wasn't public for anonymous, it resulted in 401...
Google gives me just 4 possibilities. Only I can execute it, only organization members, everyone logged with google, or everyone even anonymous. In the best-case scenario, I'd be able to add Zapier to my google organization...
Does somebody have an idea?